# Rails relational database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on building a rails app and I am starting to get stuck. I have a Model named group and I want a user to be able to join the group. The group aspect is working, I can create, delete, edit etc for a group as well as the user portion is working. The place where I am getting stuck is the connection between a user and a group. I ran this command:

```
rails g resource Student student_id:integer course_id:integer
```

To create a relational database so a user can join a group and become a student. These are the routes I have for student:

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
            students GET    /students(.:format)            students#index
                     POST   /students(.:format)            students#create
         new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)        students#new
        edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)   students#edit
             student GET    /students/:id(.:format)        students#show
                     PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)        students#update
                     PUT    /students/:id(.:format)        students#update
                     DELETE /students/:id(.:format)        students#destroy
```

How would I go about adding a user to the group using the student model. When the user is viewing the View (index) page of group there is a join button so I want it to be where when the user clicks the join button on the /views/groups/index.html.erb page it will add them to the student database. I am think I can do a <%= link_to "+ Join", ...., :method => :post %> something along those lines but I am not sure what the path would be and where to go from there. I need the controller to accept the parameters of the current_user.id and since I am looping through the groups, group.id

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to set up a relationship between User and Group. In rails, you don't need to set up tables to represent the relationship, but rather an Association. Take a read here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

For the easier case where a user can only be part of one group, we would say that a user `belongs_to :group`, and that a group `has_many :users`. By placing those lines in the respective models, you've basically already made the connection. Rails will automatically make a `.group` method for any User record, and a `.users` method for any group. There's a lot more that happens with just these simple lines so give that Rails Guide a read.

If you do want to use the Student model for the relationship, go down to the `has_many :through` section, but it doesn't really sound like that's what you want. But know that there are a lot of options when it comes to associations in rails so be sure to glance through the sections to find the kind you think you want.